# Regex in Find and Replace in Texmaker

Tags: regex, texmaker

I am searching to replace the expression below:

```
}} &  &  &  &  \\ 
   &  &  &  &  \\
```

in a tex file with the Find and Replace function (in Texmaker).
I used the Regex because of the linebreak.
I typed:

```
\}\} &\s &\s &\s &\s \\\\ \n \s & \s& \s& \s& \s\\\\
```

But the second part of the expression does not work :-( 
I think that the problem lies in the line break.

What did I miss ?

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Did you check the CRLF ending? `\r\n` instead of just `\n`? Also, use `+` to match 1 or more chars. Also, `\s` matches any whitespace, you may just replace `\s` with spaces and `\n` with just `\s+`. See [`}}(?:\s+&){4}\s+\\\\\s+(?:\s+&){4}\s+\\\\`](https://regex101.com/r/1R76EW/1)

Comment: Thanks ! I tried \r\n... Nothing works. I know the expression matches on the regex translator but not in the "Search" funtion of Texmaker. I don't understand why !

Comment: just remove '\n', in texmaker use the double backslash for line break.

Comment: The expression "\}\}(?:\s+&){4}\s+\\\\\s*" works well for the first line. But when I add: \n, \r, \r\n, \\  or &, it doesn't match anymore